# QML: define function in ListElement called in ListView

Tags: function, listview, qml

Inside a QML ListView, i'd like to call a function when a MouseArea is clicked:

```
ListView{
    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal

    model: myModel

    delegate:
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            anchors.centerin: parent
            text: label
        }
        MouseArea {
            width: 30
            height: parent.height
            onClicked: {
                doSomething()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I's supposed to be an overflow-menu. In the ListModel (myModel) i want to be able to say what happens when doSomething() is called. How do i do that? Maybe like so?

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel

    ListElement {
        label: "New"
        doSomething: {
            canvas.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea. I searched the web, but i couldn't find anything. 
I'm using a ListView/Model for this because i want to add and remove menu-entries dynamically.
Thanks for your attention! =)

Comment: What is your goal, exactly? Trigger a modification of the model w.r.t. the outcome of `doSomething()` or modifying the model from `doSomething()`?

Comment: I don't want to modify the model at all. It's supposed to be an overflow-menu. each entry should do something when you click it. Let me edit the main-post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

qrc:///main.qml:49 ListElement: cannot use script for property value

That's what you get with your code. So you can't set any property of a model element as a script.

I got away with it by putting the functions in the model, not the model element:

```qml
ListView{
    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal

    model: myModel

    delegate:
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: label
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 30
            height: parent.height
            onClicked: {
                myModel.actions[label]();
            }
        }
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: myModel

    property var actions : {
        "New": function(){ console.log("clicked!"); }
    }

    ListElement {
        label: "New"
    }
}
```

Though indexing actions based on text is kind of meh, you should probably make it so each element in the model has a unique property (like an index) and use those as the keys for the `actions` dictionnary.

(on a side note, you forgot the `centerIn` of the mouse area, and I wonder why you use a width of 30 instead of just filling the parent)

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know you can do this, thank you very much! I'll follow your advice and use indices. To answer your little side-note, Thats not my actual code, I just came up with some simpler code ;)

Comment: What I'd use in QML would be enums or strings, but 'id' strings (similar to what you would name a variable), such as 'key: "new"'. Indices could get annoying if the order of the elements in your list are changed.

Comment: If your "menu items" are not removed/rearranged during usage you can use the `index` role which is provided by default in a delegate (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#view-delegates)). So, no need to add other indices. `index` can be directly used in the `MouseArea` of the `Rectangle`.  However, as stated by @coyotte508, that would become soon annoying if the structure changes.

Comment: @coyotte508 enums! of course... thanks for pointing that out. Of course you should use enums, not indices, my bad. not only does the order change, but also the length, due to changing "permissions" or "roles". Again, thank you all for your efforts =)

Answer (score 0):

The former answers are great. However, there is another solution in case someone desire to define their functions in a JavaScript file resource or just not inline. In the first scenario, a dictionary of functions can be defined in JS as follows.

```
//JSFunc.js

var dictionaryOfFuncs= {
    "doThis":doThis,
    "doThat":doThat
}

function doThis() {
    console.log("doThis")
}

function doThat(){
    console.log("doThat")
}
```

Then, each function is defined as a string in ListModel with respect to its name in JS file.

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel
    ListElement {label: "doThis";operation:"doThis"}
    ListElement {label: "doThat";operation:"doThat"}
}
```

In the end, onClicked signal handler of Rectangle in ListView of the example would be defined like this.

```
onClicked:{
    JSFunc.dictionaryOfFuncs[operation]()
}
```

This method also works without JS resource, with defining the function dictionary as property in QML:

```
property var dictionaryOfFuncs: {
        "doThis":doThis,
        "doThat":doThat
    }
```